# ScrollView and tableview horizontal scroll conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have tried to add 2 header view in a table view first header treated as collectionView(display view) and second header as an original header... if i add scroll view and table view inside scroll view.. horizontal scroll conflict between them..
i have tried to make the tableview height static but it becomes a problem in pagination stage..

**Needed**
[image]

**Desirable**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to solve this problem. Why scrolling occurs ? because contentSizeHeight/Width is greater than
frame Height/Width, make it`s frame height/width equal or more than contentSizeHeight/Width in scrollView, it will never conflict.